# Centering a layer on click using FramerJS

Tags: coffeescript, framerjs

The goal is to move the button layer vertically upwards from the bottom the middle of the screen, whilst growing to a larger size. However, upon clicking the layer it does not move to the exact center. It moves up but shifts to the right. Why is this?

**Code**

```
bg = new BackgroundLayer
    backgroundColor: "#f39c12"

button = new Layer
    width:  100
    height: 100
    borderRadius: 100
    backgroundColor: "white"
    x: Align.center
    y: Align.bottom(-100)

button.on Events.Click, ->
    button.states.next()

button.states = 
    StateA:
        width:  300
        height: 300
        borderRadius: 300
        y: Align.center
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that Align.center is something that is only calculated when you create the layer or a state. For that reason, adding `x: Align.center` to the state also doesn't work (as you might expect it to).

However, there is an easy way to do this, by setting the `midX` property of the state to `Screen.midX`. Full example:

```
bg = new BackgroundLayer
    backgroundColor: "#f39c12"

button = new Layer
    width:  100
    height: 100
    borderRadius: 100
    backgroundColor: "white"
    x: Align.center
    y: Align.bottom(-100)

button.on Events.Click, ->
    button.states.next()

button.states = 
    StateA:
        width:  300
        height: 300
        borderRadius: 300
        y: Align.center 
        midX: Screen.midX
```

Working prototype can be found here: https://framer.cloud/RsULi

Answer (score 0):

When you enlarge the height and width of the button, the button will enlarge, but its `x` and `y` properties may not change as you expect.

Instead, try adjusting `scale` in `StateA`:

```
button.states = 
    StateA:
        borderRadius: 300
        y: Align.center
        scale: 3
```